# Custom UITableView cells to detail view

Tags: uitableview, cells, sections

[Image of what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnQlv.png)

This is something what I want to do but in a custom uitableviewcell (image, title/subtitle [be done via label if needed]) and multiple sections. The image above I did it via storyboard (static cells)

- It is going to have at least 100+ custom cells (have champ image,
  name, and title)
- Then its going to lead to a detail view with
  information on said  (image, lore, skills, etc...)
- Have multiple sections (A-Z and have different number of custom cells in there)

Hopefully someone can help me with this because  I want to get this done and its stumped me for a couple days now. If someone can either lead me to a tutorial or make one that would be just amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You have to take it back to basics, but the tableviewcell there in the image can be achieved via the standard uitableviewcell.
First change the UItabelviewCell style to subtitle
the image is set in

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
```

main text is:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"maintext";
```

detail text is:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"detailText";
```

But to answer your detailView part, you need to implement a UINavigationController. There are many tutorials on the internet to start this, but essentially, you show the UINavigationController with the tableViewController AS the ROOT controller. When you tap on the cell, it will PUSH the next view. The navigation will automatically have a back button too.

[Here is an example of a uinavigationcontroller tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/)